# Filter data frame to get only rows that have a value in column and another value in any column after first value, R

Tags: r, filter, subset

I am looking for a methodology to filter the following data frame so that I end up with only the rows that have a 1 in some column and a 2 in any other column after the column containing the 1. I am thankful for any help!

```
data_rel1 <- structure(list(job1category = c(NA, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 7, NA, 5, 1, 
5, NA, 2, 5, 1, NA, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 4, 
NA, 5, NA, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA), job2category = c(3, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, NA, 4, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 5, NA, 
4, 5, 4, NA, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 7, 5, NA, 5, 2, NA, 4, NA, 1, 5, 
NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, NA, 4, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA), job3category = c(3, 
2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, NA, 4, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 
5, NA, 4, 5, 4, NA, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 7, 5, NA, 5, 2, NA, 4, NA, 
1, 5, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, NA, 4, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA), 
    job4category = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 
    1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
    4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 
    NA, 4, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 5, NA, 4, 5, 4, NA, 5, 
    2, 4, 4, 2, 7, 5, NA, 5, 2, NA, 4, NA, 1, 5, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 5, 2, NA, 4, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with an `apply` -

```
data_rel1[apply(data_rel1, 1, function(x) {
  inds <- which(x == 1)
  length(inds) && any(which(x == 2)  > min(inds))
}), ]

#  job1category job2category job3category job4category
#         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1            1            2            2            2
#2            1            2            2            2
#3            1            2            2            2
#4            1            2            2            2
#5            1            2            2            2
#6            1            2            2            2
#7            1            2            2            2
#8            1            2            2            2
```

Comment: thank you so much! Does this also work when I want to find all rows that have e.g. a 3 in some column and then a 1 after the 3 somewhere? (instead of 1 and then 2)

Comment: Yes, it should work. You need 2 changes. Change `inds <- which(x == 1)` to `inds <- which(x == 3)` and `which(x == 2)` to `which(x == 1)` to get a 1 after 3.